# Why cloud foundry needs majority of AZs accessible?

Tags: cloud-foundry

When reading cloud foundry document about AZs, it mentions:

> Cloud Foundry maintains its availability as long as a majority of the AZs remain accessible. For example, a three-AZ deployment stays up when one entire AZ goes down, and a five-AZ deployment can withstand an outage of up to two AZs with no impact on uptime

I don't understand why? my understanding is a three-AZ deployment stays up when one AZ still accessible, same with a five-AZ deployment, how should I understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose AZ 1 loses connectivity to AZ 2 and AZ 3. AZ 1 assumes that AZ 2 and AZ 3 have failed, and begins spinning up workloads from AZ 2 and 3 to get back to capacity. In the meantime, AZ 2 and AZ 3 believe that AZ 1 has failed, and it starts spinning up redundant workloads because it believes that cluster is the sole survivor. You now have two rogue clusters running competing workloads.

The only way to prevent that scenario, and to ensure that your workloads are only running in one cluster, is to require a majority of connected AZs to be designated the sole survivor.